# .parent() not affecting immediate parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've made a little demonstration of my problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/nt3Z3/

I'm using Bootstrap v3.1 and jQuery v1.11 and in my contact form I have ~5 inputs and ~1 textarea:

```
<fieldset>
<div class="form-group"> <!-- Only Posting one for size purposes -->
  <label for="nameBox" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
  <div id="nameGroup" class="col-lg-10">
    <input type="text" id="nameBox" class="form-control" placeholder="John Smith" required="" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="messageBox" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
  <div id="messageGroup" class="col-lg-10">
    <textarea id="messageBox" class="form-control" placeholder="Your content here" required="" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary center-block">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
```

In my js file I have something along the lines of:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function () {
  var name = $.trim($("#nameBox").val());

  if ($("input, textarea").val() == "") {
    $(this).parent().addClass("has-error");
  }
});
```

I've imported jquery's latest straight from Google's API.

So, back to the problem. When I click the submit button with nothing in the text boxes the fieldset gets the class `has-error` when only the div `nameGroup` (and so on) should have. I've attempted to remove the `$.trim` to see if that was the problem and that did no success.

What my final output should be when I press the submit button and no text is in any of the inputs should look like

```
<fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Name</label>
  <div id="nameGroup" class="col-lg-10 has-error">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

But with the current js I have above, I get this

```
<fieldset class="has-error"> <!-- go away has-error -->
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Name</label>
  <div id="nameGroup" class="col-lg-10 has-error">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Am I doing something wrong? Overlooking something? Is there an easy way to have the fieldset not acquire the `has-error` class without saying `$("fieldset").removeClass("has-error");` or without putting `$("#nameGroup").addClass("has-error");` for each group?

Comment: It has an ID, so why not just `$('#nameGroup').addClass("has-error");` ?

Comment: @adeneo I'm trying to prevent from writing that 6 (or more in the future) times. If I have no other choice but to write it like that, then I'll suck it up and write it like that.

Comment: Well, then it's `$(this).prev().find('div').addClass("has-error"); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
if ($("input, textarea").val() == "") {
  $(this).parent().addClass("has-error");
}
```

Puts the class on the parent of `#submitButton` (since it's in a `click` handler on `#submitButton`). It also only checks the value of the **first** `input` or `textarea` on the page (not the others).

If you want it on, say, the parent of each individual input or text box, then:

```
$("input, textarea").each(function() {
  if (!$.trim(this.value)) {
      $(this).parent().addClass("has-error");
  }
});
```

or if you like

```
$("input, textarea").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if (!$.trim($this.val())) {
      $this.parent().addClass("has-error");
  }
});
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh. I see how the `.parent()` is affecting the `fieldset` instead of the `div`... Would've never guessed that. Also, never knew about the `.each()` function, thank you.

Comment: @collinhaines: Glad that helped! You might want to take an hour or two and just read the API front-to-back, it really only takes that long. There are some slightly tricky things, like the fact that functions like `val` (e.g., ones that can be used either to get information or set information -- `val`, `attr`, `prop`, and so on) are *asymmetrical*: When you're *getting* information, they only get it from the first element in the set, but when you're *setting*, they set it on all (which is why your code was only checking the first `input`/`textarea` on the page). Best,

Answer (score 0):

The buttons' parent is the fieldset. Not the form-group.
If you want to target the form-group you can do this:

```
.parent().find('.form-group');
```